# If vs overloads vs reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism

I have **a lot** of classes with proprties like:

```
class C1
{
    [PropName("Prop1")]
    public string A {get;set;}

    [PropName("Prop2")]
    public string B {get;set;}

    [PropName("Prop3")]
    public string C {get;set;}
} 

class C2
{
    [PropName("Prop1")]
    public string D {get;set;}

    [PropName("Prop2")]
    public string E {get;set;}

    [PropName("Prop3")]
    public string F {get;set;}
}
```

The attribute tells what is the actual property but the name of the C# property doesn't always match. In the case of C1 and C2, C1.A is the same property as C2.D.

These classes are not part of any inheritance chain and I don't have control over them so I cannot change them.

There are some common operations for "Prop1", "Prop2", ... , "PropN". What is the best solution to write these operations without too much code repetition but still make it maintainable.

Solution #1 (if statements - lots of them)

```
void OperationWithProp1(object o)
{
    string prop1;        

    C1 class1 = o as C1;
    if (class1 != null)
        prop1 = class1.A;

    C2 class2 = o as C2;
    if (class2 != null)
        prop1 = class2.D;

    // Do something with prop1
}
```

Solution #2 (overloads - lots of them)

```
void OperationWithProp1(string prop1)
{
    // Do something with prop1
}

void RunOperationWithProp1(C1 class1)
{
    OperationWithProp1(class1.A);
}

void RunOperationWithProp1(C2 class2)
{
    OperationWithProp1(class2.D);
}
```

Solution #3 (Reflection) - I'm worried about perf because each of these operations will be called thousands of times and there a few hundred operations

```
void OperationWithProp1(object o)
{
     // Pseudo code:
     // Get all properties from o that have the PropName attribute
     // Look if any attribute matches "Prop1"
     // Get the value of the property that matches
     // Do something with the value of the property
}
```

Which solution would you pick and why? Do you have other patterns in mind?

---

EDIT for clarifications:

A lot of classes means tens of them

A lot of properties means 30-40 properties/class

Comment: On the face of it, I might go with with #2 just for compile-time safety and to avoid excessive casting. It might depend on what "lots of them" actually is: can you provide some practical sense of scale for your usage? Are we talking on the order of a dozen, several dozen, or hundred+? EDIT: Another option is to provide your own object wrappers that deal with this and hide the nastiness to your outward facing API/business logic.

Comment: If you don't expect to write a LOT of boilerplate, the better way is reflection, you can cache some things such as `PropertyInfo` instances to speed it up a little.

Comment: I believe reflection provides the same speed hit whether you use it once or repeatedly - it just takes a bit of time to examine everything the first time it's called or something like that. (I'm not entirely sure.)

Comment: @Bobson Really depends on how you leverage it; I imagine there is _some_ caching done by the reflection API behind the scenes, but gains will probably be minimal in comparison to using reflection _at all_. (Some libraries that wrap reflection will do their own caching or writing IL at runtime to make it fast, so you could leverage those rather than reflection directly. I _think_ the `dynamic` objects have some caching too) EDIT: Maybe I misunderstood you. :) I'm all scatterbrained today!

Answer (score 4):

You can make a wrapper class exposing the properties that you need, and wrapping *instances* of the actual `C1` and `C2` classes. One way of doing it would be through delegates:

```
interface WithProperties {
   string A {get;set;}
   string B {get;set;}
   string C {get;set;}
}
class WrappedCX<T> : WithProperties {
    private readonly T wrapped;
    private readonly Func<T,string> getA;
    private readonly Action<T,string> setA;
    private readonly Func<T,string> getB;
    private readonly Action<T,string> setB;
    private readonly Func<T,string> getC;
    private readonly Action<T,string> setC;
    public WrappedCX(T obj, Func<T,string> getA, Action<T,string> setA, Func<T,string> getB, Action<T,string> setB, Func<T,string> getC, Action<T,string> setC) {
        wrapped = obj;
        this.getA = getA;
        this.setA = setA;
        this.getB = getB;
        this.setB = setB;
        this.getC = getC;
        this.setC = setC;
    }
    public string A {
        get {return getA(wrapped);}
        set {setA(wrapped, value);}
    }
    public string B {
        get {return getB(wrapped);}
        set {setB(wrapped, value);}
    }
    public string C {
        get {return getC(wrapped);}
        set {setC(wrapped, value);}
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
C1 c1 = new C1();
C2 c2 = new C2();
WithProperties w1 = new WrappedCX(c1, c => c.A, (c,v) => {c.A=v;}, c => c.B, (c,v) => {c.B=v;}, c => c.C, (c,v) => {c.C=v;});
WithProperties w2 = new WrappedCX(c2, c => c.D, (c,v) => {c.D=v;}, c => c.E, (c,v) => {c.E=v;}, c => c.F, (c,v) => {c.F=v;});
```

At this point, `w1` and `w2` are both implementing the common `WithProperties` interface, so you can use them without checking their type.

To get fancy, replace the seven-argument constructor with a constructor that takes a single `obj` parameter, obtain its class via reflection, check its properties for the custom attributes that you defined, and create/compile LINQ expressions corresponding to the getters and the setters of the properties `A`, `B`, and `C`. This would let you construct your `WrappedCX` without the ugly lambdas trailing in the call. The tradeoff here is that now the lambdas would be constructed at run time, so would-be compile errors on missing properties would become run-time exceptions.

Comment: I did not try compiling this, so there may be minor syntax errors in there. The overall strategy should be good, though. Let me know if you catch errors in the code, and I'll edit the answer to fix them.

Comment: I think this approach would work somewhat better if one started by defining a converter interface `IAccessor<T>` which would store or fetch the appropriate properties to or from a T.  If one did that, had a static class `Accessors<T>` with a single field `Accessor` of type `IAccessor<T>`, and for each suitable type set `Accessors<TT>.Accessor` to something that implemented `IAccessor<TT>`, then given a variable `it` of any generic type `TTT` which had a converter installed, one could set property1 to "Fred" using something like `Accessors<TTT>.Accessor.SetProperty1(it, "Fred");`.

Comment: @supercat Right - that could be one way of implementing the "get fancy" approach from the answer.

Comment: I guess the question would be whether one wants to require that a wrapper is built at the same time as the underlying object, and require that all code that would pass around the object must pass around the wrapper instead, or whether one wants to allow code to pass around the original object type while retaining the ability to access its properties.  If some code will need to use things as their underlying type, the wrapper approach would tend to violate one of my OOP rules: exactly one entity should regard any mutable aspect of system state as being part of its own state.

Answer (score 3):

You could dynamically generate proxy classes that access the correct members using the attributed "PropName" names.  You'd also want to detect if the properties actually implement get/set before generating calls to them.  Also maybe a more sophisticated method to guarantee unique type names for the generated proxies...

See Main() for usage, and below main is an implementation of your OperationWithProp1()

(Here comes a lot of code)

```
public interface IC
{
    string Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
    string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class C1
{
    [PropName("Prop1")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [PropName("Prop2")]
    public string B { get; set; }

    [PropName("Prop3")]
    public string C { get; set; }
}

public class C2
{
    [PropName("Prop1")]
    public string D { get; set; }

    [PropName("Prop2")]
    public string E { get; set; }

    [PropName("Prop3")]
    public string F { get; set; }
}

public class ProxyBuilder
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Type> _proxyClasses = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Type>();

    private static readonly AssemblyName _assemblyName = new AssemblyName("ProxyBuilderClasses");
    private static readonly AssemblyBuilder _assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(_assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
    private static readonly ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder = _assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(_assemblyName.Name, _assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

    public static void SaveProxyAssembly()
    {
        _assemblyBuilder.Save(_assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
    }

    public static Type GetProxyTypeForBackingType(Type proxyInterface, Type backingType)
    {
        var key = Tuple.Create(proxyInterface, backingType);

        Type returnType;
        if (_proxyClasses.TryGetValue(key, out returnType))
            return returnType;

        var typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(
            "ProxyClassProxies." + "Proxy_" + proxyInterface.Name + "_To_" + backingType.Name,
            TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed,
            typeof (Object),
            new[]
            {
                proxyInterface
            });

        //build backing object field
        var backingObjectField = typeBuilder.DefineField("_backingObject", backingType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        //build constructor
        var ctor = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, new[] {backingType});
        var ctorIL = ctor.GetILGenerator();
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        var ctorInfo = typeof (Object).GetConstructor(types: Type.EmptyTypes);
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctorInfo);
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, backingObjectField);
        ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        foreach (var targetPropertyInfo in backingType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            var propertyName = targetPropertyInfo.Name;
            var attributes = targetPropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (PropName), true);

            if (attributes.Length > 0 && attributes[0] != null)
                propertyName = (attributes[0] as PropName).Name;

            var propBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, targetPropertyInfo.PropertyType, null);

            const MethodAttributes getSetAttrs =
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.Virtual;

            //build get method
            var getBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                "get_" + propertyName,
                getSetAttrs,
                targetPropertyInfo.PropertyType,
                Type.EmptyTypes);

            var getIL = getBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, backingObjectField);
            getIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, targetPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod(), Type.EmptyTypes);
            getIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            propBuilder.SetGetMethod(getBuilder);

            //build set method
            var setBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
                "set_" + propertyName,
                getSetAttrs,
                null,
                new[] {targetPropertyInfo.PropertyType});

            var setIL = setBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, backingObjectField);
            setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIL.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, targetPropertyInfo.GetSetMethod(), new[] {targetPropertyInfo.PropertyType});
            setIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            propBuilder.SetSetMethod(setBuilder);
        }
        returnType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        _proxyClasses.Add(key, returnType);
        return returnType;
    }

    public static TIProxy CreateProxyObject<TIProxy>(object backingObject, out TIProxy outProxy) where TIProxy : class
    {
        var t = GetProxyTypeForBackingType(typeof (TIProxy), backingObject.GetType());
        outProxy = Activator.CreateInstance(t, backingObject) as TIProxy;
        return outProxy;
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c1 = new C1();
        IC c1Proxy;
        CreateProxyObject(c1, out c1Proxy);
        var c2 = new C2();
        IC c2Proxy;
        CreateProxyObject(c2, out c2Proxy);

        c1Proxy.Prop1 = "c1Prop1Value";
        Debug.Assert(c1.A.Equals("c1Prop1Value"));

        c2Proxy.Prop1 = "c2Prop1Value";
        Debug.Assert(c2.D.Equals("c2Prop1Value"));

        //so you can check it out in reflector
        SaveProxyAssembly();
    }

    private static void OperationWithProp1(object o)
    {
        IC proxy;
        CreateProxyObject(o, out proxy);

        string prop1 = proxy.Prop1;

        // Do something with prop1
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, go with overloads for clarity/maintainability.  If there's a lot of overlapping code, break it into a seperate method.

That being said, I'm assuming you are first concerned with maintainability, since you don't mention speed.

Comment: "Which solution would you pick and **why**?"

Comment: I don't like using overloads for such purposes, since they don't interact well with generics.  Conceptually, one should be able to write a method which can accept a parameter of generic type T, and access property1 for any passed-in object which has an appropriate property, but C# can only pass an argument of type `T` to an overload which can accept all types `T` could possibly be.

Answer (score 1):

For best performance, you should write a pair of static methods for each property, of the form:

```
[PropName("Prop1")]
static string Prop1Getter(thisType it) { return it.WhateverProperty; }
[PropName("Prop1")]
static string Prop1Setter(thisType it, string st) { it.WhateverProperty = st; }
```

I would suggest that you then use Reflection to generate delegates, and and static generic classes to cache them.  Effectively, you'd have a private static class `PropertyAccessors<T>` which had delegates declared like like:

```
const int numProperties = 3;
public Func<T, string>[] Getters;
public Action<T, string>[] Setters;
```

The static constructor would then do something like:

```
Getters = new Func<T, string>[numProperties];
Setters = new Action<T, string>[numProperties];
for (int i = 0; i< numProperties; i++)
{
  int ii = i;  // Important--ensure closure is inside loop
  Getters[ii] = (T it) => FindSetAndRunGetter(ii, it);
  Setters[ii] = (T it, string st) => FindSetAndRunSetter(ii, it, st);
}
```

The `FindSetAndRunGetter(ii,it)` method should search for an appropriate property getter, and--if found--set `Getters[ii]` to point to the appropriate property getter, run it once, and return the result.  `FindSetAndRunSetter(ii, it, st)` should do likewise with a property setter, running it once with `st` as a parameter.

Using this approach would combine the versatility and "automatic upgrading" of using Reflection (meaning the ability to automatically find methods in future classes), with speed comparable to (if not better than) that of hard-coded approaches.  The one annoyance is the need to define the static methods as described above.  It would probably be possible to use `Reflection.Emit` to auto-generate static classes containing such methods, but that be beyond my level of expertise.